# Downloading build files from Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, python-requests

I have list of builds in Jenkins in URL

```
http://<hostname>/ci/view/XX-CI/job/XX-2%20UI%20Demo/ws/build/dist/
```

The Jenkins needs a login and it is authenticated using Google accounts.

I am trying a simple python script using Requests to looks for latest files in the build location and download the same.

To look for latest files, I wrote a simple python script as follows. My idea is to get a HTML response and parse the html response to get the latest build filename and download the same.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests

resp = requests.get('http://<hostname>/ci/view/XX-CI/job/XX-2%20UI%20Demo/ws/build/dist/', auth=('username', 'pass')) 
print rep.text
```

I got something like below as output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <title>Sign in - Google Accounts</title>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=https://www.google.com/accounts/AccountChooser?hd=accedo.tv&amp;
```

It means my authentication details which I passed in the script is not successful.

Does google accounts cannot be authenticated this way? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the [API token](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/api-token-jenkins-rest-api)?

With this solution, you can use this kind of URL:

```
http://username:api-token@<hostname>/ci/view/XX-CI/job/XX-2%20UI%20Demo/ws/build/dist/
```

It should do the job :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that too but still the same output and the response shows text "Sign In"